# Default Directory for packages

Tags: java

I am a newbie in java I Want to know that what is the default directory for packages in java ? I Mean if i compile a java file which contains a package statement,and i compile it without using `-d` option in `javac` command,then where will be the package created ? eg.

```
package test;
class Test{}
```

and compile it using `javac Test.java`
then where will be the package created?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-d` option in `javac` command is use to specify where to generate the class file,if you don't specify it,then the `.class` file will be created in the same directory where your `.java` file is present.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't specify `-d`, the class file will be created in the same directory as the source file.

That's fine *if* you're already storing your source in a directory structure matching your package structure (and if you're happy for your source and class files to live in the same place) but if your source structure *doesn't* match your package structure, you'll basically end up with class files in locations where they can't sensibly be used.

Personally for anything other than quick throwaway (usually Stack Overflow :) code I would make the following suggestions:

- Avoid using the default package
- Keep your source code in a directory structure (e.g. with a root of `src`) matching package structure
- Generate class files into a separate directory structure (e.g. with a root of `bin` or `out` or `classes`)

(Sorry, misread the question to start with.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no directory created when you do not specify the package!
all the `.class` files will be created directly in the output folder

```
public class A{}
```

if you compile this to output folder ,

`output/a.class`  is created